# Overriding Mailer service in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, dependency-injection, laravel-5.4, service-provider

I am trying to override the default implementation of `Mailer` in `Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider`.

At first, I thought that I will just extend the service and switch the implementation in the container followingly:

**App\Mail\Mailer**

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

class Mailer extends \Illuminate\Mail\Mailer
{
    public function getTo()
    {
        return $this->to;
    }
}
```

**App\Providers\AppServiceProvider**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;


class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('mailer', function (Container $app) {

            // ...

            $mailer = new \App\Mail\Mailer(
                $app['view'], $app['swift.mailer'], $app['events']
            );

            // ...

            return $mailer;
        });
    }
}
```

> The problem is that even though I've overridden the container definition when resolving the service it ignores my definition completely because `Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider` has `$defer = true` property, meaning that it will get resolved in a special way like this:

**Illuminate\Foundation\Application**

```
public function make($abstract)
{
    $abstract = $this->getAlias($abstract);

    if (isset($this->deferredServices[$abstract])) {
        $this->loadDeferredProvider($abstract);
    }

    return parent::make($abstract);
}
```

So, it doesn't matter that I tried to override the service, because `Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider` will always get preferred since it's `deferred` service provider. I tried defining my service provider as `$defer = true` as well but without luck.

The only option that I can think of would be to completely remove `Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider` and replace it with a custom one. But that seems a bit harsh.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can see that this commit has [5.4] prefix but it never made it to the 5.4 branch: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/20714/files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to solve this issue is to upgrade Laravel to version `5.5` and above. The fixed version is referenced in [this issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/25676) and won't be fixed in `5.4` since the version is no longer supported.